# AppCompatActivity Gradle Error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I tried to modify an app by changing `ActionBarActivity` in `AppCompatActivity`.
I also changed the `build.gradle` file, attach the modified version.

Now when I try to run the program I get an error message:

[image]

How do I run the program?

********** build.gradle *********

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "it.giocoparole.trovanagramma"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 3
    versionName "0.9.2"
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("C:\\AndroidStudioKeystore\\TrovAnagramma.jks")
        storePassword "xxxxx"
        keyAlias "Alias_TrovAnagramma"
        keyPassword "xxxxx"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release


        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        zipAlignEnabled true
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 21` and `targetSdkVersion 23` interesting ... `compileSdkVersion 21`  and `'com.android.support:******:23.1.1'` even more interesting

Comment: I can not add an image, recover link to drobbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6s9tusjb0ax61h/Error-Gradle.png?dl=0

Comment: Either change your `compileSdkVersion` to 23 or your support libs version to 21

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this combination:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.x.x
```

You have to use the same version to compile. Then you can use:

Best choice:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.x.x
```

or

```
compileSdkVersion 21
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.x.x
```